# is there any way to solve this error in python?

Tags: python, pandas, sparse-matrix

```
sparse_ratings = csr_matrix(pd.DataFrame.sparse.from_spmatrix(most_rated_movies_1k).to_coo())

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-35-6002e81c5a88> in <module>
      1 # Conversion to sparse csr matrix
      2 
----> 3 sparse_ratings = csr_matrix(pd.DataFrame.sparse.from_spmatrix(most_rated_movies_1k).to_coo())

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\pandas\core\arrays\sparse\accessor.py in from_spmatrix(cls, data, index, columns)
    230         from pandas import DataFrame
    231 
--> 232         data = data.tocsc()
    233         index, columns = cls._prep_index(data, index, columns)
    234         sparrays = [SparseArray.from_spmatrix(data[:, i]) for i in range(data.shape[1])]

~\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\pandas\core\generic.py in __getattr__(self, name)
   5272             if self._info_axis._can_hold_identifiers_and_holds_name(name):
   5273                 return self[name]
-> 5274             return object.__getattribute__(self, name)
   5275 
   5276     def __setattr__(self, name: str, value) -> None:

AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'tocsc'
```

when i run this code, it shows this error. actually i am apllying k means clustering on movielens dataset.

Comment: Hi @babljeet, welcome to SO. You are passing a data frame to the csr_matrix - you want something like a 2d numpy array. You can get that from a data frame with df.values. But you are also making it a data frame within that function, so I’m wondering what exactly you are trying to achieve. Would be helpful if you show some more code.

Comment: hi @BertilJohannesIpsen. Thank you so much for your response. if i am writing this sparse_ratings = csr_matrix(pd.SparseDataFrame(most_rated_movies_1k).to_coo()), then SparseDataFrame() takes no arguments this error is displayed. i am trying this code https://towardsdatascience.com/unsupervised-classification-project-building-a-movie-recommender-with-clustering-analysis-and-4bab0738efe6

Comment: The error message says you're trying to call [scipy function `scipy.sparse.coo_matrix.tocsc()`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.coo_matrix.tocsc.html) on a **pandas** dataframe (which has [different methods](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/frame.html)).

Answer (score 0):

According to the new version of pandas (1.1.x), the syntax has been changed:

```
sp_arr = csr_matrix(most_rated_movies_1k)
sdf = pd.DataFrame.sparse.from_spmatrix(sp_arr)
sparse_ratings = sdf.sparse.to_coo()
```

Hopefully, this will work for you.

Comment: your answer seems ok, but you can add references to your statement

Comment: Can you please add the specific number of the pandas version (1.1.x?) and preferably a [link to its release notes](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/whatsnew/index.html) Nothing ages faster, or is harder to reinterpret in the future, than "current", "latest", "recent", "stable".

Comment: Link from where i got this information-> https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/sparse.html#interaction-with-scipy-sparse